# how to change a column type in a struct by pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

here's dataframe which contains a struct field, I would like to change one column type from string to int in this struct, how should I do it by pyspark? this struct has many columns, I can't re-struct it

```
structureSchema = StructType([
        StructField('name', StructType([
             StructField('firstname', StringType(), True),
             StructField('middlename', StringType(), True),
             StructField('lastname', StringType(), True)
             ])),
         StructField('id', StringType(), True),
         StructField('gender', StringType(), True),
         StructField('salary', IntegerType(), True)
         ])
```

just give an example, I would like to change `id` column type to IntegerType

Comment: For Spark 3.1+, you can try using [`withField`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.withField.html#pyspark.sql.Column.withField): `df.withColumn("structCol", F.col("structCol").withField("id", F.col("structCol.id").cast("int")))`

Comment: Good one @blackbishop. Cool

Comment: cool, it works, thanks

Comment: This should be submitted as the answer to the question